# When I restore the saved graph and variables. how can I get the placehold in TF

Tags: tensorflow

I have used

```
 tf.add_to_collection('Input', X)
 tf.add_to_collection('TrueLabel', Y)
 tf.add_to_collection('loss', loss)
 tf.add_to_collection('accuracy', accuracy)

 saver0 = tf.train.Saver()
 saver0.save(sess, './save/model')
 saver0.export_meta_graph('./save/model.meta')
```

to save my code in one session scope. Then, I restore it from another session scope. CUrrent, I only has the training data, and I have save the placeholder X, and Y. WHile I cannot use them at this time:

```
train_data, train_label = get_data()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./save/model.meta')
    new_saver.restore(sess, './save/model')
    graph = sess.graph
    X = graph.get_collection('Input')
    Y = graph.get_collection('TrueLabel')
    loss = graph.get_collection('loss')
    accuracy = graph.get_collection('accuracy')
    for _ in range(5):
        loss_str, accuracy_str = sess.run([loss, accuracy], {X:train_data, Y:train_label})
        print('loss:{}, accuracy:{}'.format(loss_str, accuracy_str))
```

How can I do that? I found the tutorial docs did not give a complete example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This concern has been solved by myself. Once we load the graph and the variables. Just to obtain the placeholder like graph.get_tensor_by_name('Input:0'). Use the same way to obtain the loss and accuracy and so on what you want to collect.

A full example could be found from https://github.com/sunkevin1214/TF_implementation/blob/master/test_funs/test_save_load.py